# Why doesn't this autocomplete field work?

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, autocomplete

I'm trying to use [this autocomplete field](http://loopj.com/jquery-tokeninput/) with a set of prepopulated genres.

Genre has a has_and_belongs_to_many association with Profile.

I have this in my routes:

```
resources :profiles
resources :genres
```

This is my genres controller:

```
respond_to :html, :json

def index
  respond_with(@genres = Genre.search(params[:q]))
end
```

And this is my Genre model:

```
has_and_belongs_to_many :videos
has_and_belongs_to_many :profiles

scope :search, lambda {|q| where("name LIKE ?", '%q%') }
```

This is in my application.js:

```
$("#genre_field").tokenInput(genres_path);
```

This is my profile edit view:

```
<%= f.fields_for :genre do |g| %>
 <div class="field">
      <%= g.label :name, "Genres" %><br />
      <%= g.text_field :name, :id => 'genre_field' %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I've already prepopulated the genres table with a set of genres and I include the `jquery.tokeninput.js` and CSS files.

So why is the text field not showing the autocomplete results? What am I missing?

Comment: Your where clause has a quotation typo, is it like that in the code as well? `where("name LIKE ?', "%q%') }` should be `where("name LIKE ?", '%q%') }`

Comment: yea... still can't get it to work though

Comment: In the line `$("#genre_field").tokenInput(genres_path);` is genres_path in a variable in the script?

Comment: no but isn't it the correct named route for the index action? Isn't that the url that I want to pass to `.tokenInput()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comments I think I've figured out your problem. In your application.js you have the following:

`$("#genre_field").tokenInput(genres_path);`

which maps the DOM element `#genre_field` to receive data from `genres_path`.

`genres_path`, however, does not exist in the context of your JavaScript file. The method `genres_path` exists in ruby because rails generates that method via routes.rb, not in JS. In order to fix this you'll need to provide the relative path that `genres_path` represents in your JS code:

`$("#genre_field").tokenInput("/path/to/genres");`

**or**

You need to create some sort of js.erb file that makes use of `genres_path`:

`$("#genre_field").tokenInput(<%= genres_path %>);`

**or**

You can add an inline script to your html.erb file that handles all of this code in a similar fashion to the js.erb file:

```
<%= f.fields_for :genre do |g| %>
 <div class="field">
     <%= g.label :name, "Genres" %><br />
     <%= g.text_field :name, :id => 'genre_field' %>
 </div>
<% end %>

<script>
    $("#genre_field").tokenInput(<%= genres_path %>);
</script>
```

Comment: If it were me I'd go with the first choice: `$("#genre_field").tokenInput("/path/to/genres");` in my JS file. It's simple and doesn't require a new file or embedding a script in the html. That being said, you're hard-coding a path in your JS that can't be linked back to your rails app directly. So if you change the path in any way you'll get an error, but you should be able to track it down quickly -- especially if you use a tool like Firebug to diagnose problems.

Comment: I'm confused... I literally pass it `"/path/to/genres"`? JS provides that path?

Comment: Sorry no, that's just a notation I've seen in some tutorials here and there. You'll pass the actual path in, whatever that may be. Ex: `$("#genre_field").tokenInput("/genres");`

Comment: thanks, but there must be some other error I'm making or some code I'm leaving out because the autocomplete suggestions are still not being generated...

Comment: Alright let's work through this step by step. First, is your controller being hit correctly? Check via Firebug or Chrome that a successful connection was made to your controller (it will be red in Firebug if unsuccessful). If the controller is not being hit, paste the url that the browser is trying to navigate to.

Comment: I think things will be more efficient if we do this in chat:http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/633/ruby-on-rails

Comment: by the way... my Chrome console gives me this error: `jquery.tokeninput.js:92 Uncaught TypeError: Object function (a,b){return new c.fn.init(a,b)} has no method 'type'`

Comment: @McStretch I thought you'd be interested that this works: `format.json {render :json => @genres.map(&:attributes).to_json}` I got the code from someone on IRC.

Comment: I'm not really sure what it does... it'd be interested to know

Comment: Yeah that's what I was looking to do. For some reason I was looking at hash methods rather than array. Map does the following: "Invokes block once for each element of self. Creates a new array containing the values returned by the block." As for &:attributes, it's a shortcut to say "call the method attributes on each element in the array", which works because each element is a Genre object.